# How to delet "Text" tag value if the ID of this element will be match with "value"

Tags: xslt

I tried below code:
Input:

```
<assessment>
   <response>
      <option>
         <value>A G1</value>
         <value>B G2</value>
      </option>
   </response>
   <item>
      <gap>
         <p>Identify the <gap identifier="G1"/>missing words in<gap identifier="G2"/> this famous quote from Shakespeare's Richard III.</p>
         <Text identifier="A">winter</Text>
         <Text identifier="C">spring</Text>
         <Text identifier="D">summer</Text>
         <Text identifier="B">autumn</Text>
      </gap>
   </item>
</assessment>
```

Current Output:

```
<text>
   <txt>spring</txt>
   <txt>summer</txt>
   <txt>autumn</txt>
   <txt>winter</txt>
   <txt>spring</txt>
   <txt>autumn</txt>
</text>
```

Expected Output:

```
<text>
<txt>spring</txt>
<txt>summer</txt>
</text>
```

XSLT:

```
       <xsl:if test="//response/option">
          <xsl:for-each select="//option/value">
             <xsl:variable name="answer" select="."/>
             <xsl:variable name="answer_id" select="substring-before($answer, ' ')"/>
             <xsl:for-each select="//Text">
                <xsl:variable name="answer_id1" select="@identifier"/>
                <xsl:if test="not($answer_id=$answer_id1)">
                   <text>
<txt>
                      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                   </txt>
</text>
                </xsl:if>
             </xsl:for-each>
          </xsl:for-each>
       </xsl:if>
```

I also tried to create global variable and store "value" text inside this but the variable store whole content while we need to capture content before space.

Answer (score 0):

Your current XSL processes each <value> element, parsing out the first part of the string content as $answer_id.
For each <value> element, it processes each of the 6 <Text> elements.
If the <Text> element's @identifier doesn't match $answer_id, that element is written out.

So when the "A G1" <value> element is processed, it compares all 6 Text elements against "A" and writes out: spring, summer, and autumn.
Then when the "B G2" <value> element is processed, it compares all 6 Text elements against "B" and writes out: winter, spring, summer.

But you want to output the Text elements that don't match up to any of the option values.
So you should process each Text element only once, comparing it to both A and B. Only if it matches neither, then output it.
Using XSL, this is easiest to do by concatenating the values to be compared against into a single variable.

For example:

```
   <xsl:if test="//response/option">
      <xsl:variable name="valuesToOmit">
         <xsl:for-each select="//option/value">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., ' ')"/>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:variable>
      <text>
         <xsl:for-each select="//Text">
            <xsl:if test="not(contains($valuesToOmit, @identifier))">
               <txt>
                  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
               </txt>
            </xsl:if>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </text>
   </xsl:if>
```

When this XSL is executed against the input, $valuesToOmit will contain "AB". 
The "winter" Text element will match on A, so won't be output.
The "spring" Text element won't match on A or B and will be output.
The "summer" Text element won't match on A or B and will be output.
The "autumn" Text element will match on B, so won't be output.

Answer (score 0):

XSLT has a built-in [**key**](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#key) mechanism for resolving cross-references. Here is how you could use it in your example:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="val" match="value" use="substring-before(., ' ')" />

<xsl:template match="/assessment">
    <text>
        <xsl:for-each select="item/gap/Text[not(key('val', @identifier))]">
            <txt>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </txt>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </text>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you so Much for quick response. The easier solution to handle using xsl:key.